# Blender: Render Very High CPU usage

Tags: rendering, render, cpu, blender, cpu-usage

I'm new to Blender. My question is: I'm pretty sure that over 1000% CPU usage is not normal when I render, but could it be dangerous for my computer?

This is a screenshoot:[image]

I know that a good GPU could be the answer..
I usually work on very simple scene.
I just want to know if it's dangerous or not.

I've tried all the possible combination in Blender Settings. (Cycles Render Device, GPU backend)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds normal to me; I'd hope it would be multithreaded and able to take advantage of all your cores for something computationally intensive like rendering.  It's not dangerous for your hardware; at worst the CPU will protect itself from overheating by reducing its clock speed to something below the normal rated all-cores "base" non-turbo frequency.  (But that should only happen if your cooling system is clogged with dust, or your CPU heat sink fell off.)

Comment: Don't worry, I've pushed hardware hard for 3 decades and nothing has ever caught fire :) At worst it will shorten the lifespan a bit but of course we all upgrade every few years anyway. Regarding the rendering it's very intensive. I'm making a game that to bake the lightmap takes my 4070ti and i9 a few hours.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, they really reassure me!